# Heroku MERN deployment. Error: Cannot find module

Tags: heroku

The deployment is successful but the it cannot find modules.

I suppose that the problem might be in the project structure I am using:

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── client
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── build
│   ...
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│       
├── package.json
└── server
    ├── main.js
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── routes
    │  ...
```

I have 3 package.json files. One in client, one in server (having all of the dependencies) and one at the root of the project specifically for heroku to work. The one in the root has only `heroku-postbuild` and other scripts and does not have any dependencies. All of the deplendencies needed are in the `server/package.json`.

The deployment went successfully, but it crushes saying that it cannot find a module (dotenv specifically) that is used in the `server/main.js`

Comment: Forgot to mention the scripts look like this ```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd server && npm start",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer was actually quite simple. I had to change the start script in the root of the project to `"start": "cd server && npm install && npm start"` so it makes sure that all of the modules are installed remotely.